# Selenium IDE window focus in Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm using selenium IDE and webdriver to test a web page in Internet Explorer.  I discovered a while back that IE will not fully accept commands from Selenium if it's not the window in focus.  For example, if the Selenium IDE window is in focus, and the command is to click a button in IE, the button will push down, but it won't let go.

With that in mind, my test involves popping up a window, doing a few things in it, leaving it open and returning to the null window to do a few things, then returning to the popup for a few more commands.

Is there a way I can make the null window come forward (over the popup) when I need to execute the commands for the null window?  And then vice versa, can I make the popup then come forward when I need to return to it?  I tried using `windowFocus`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [SwitchTo()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) method and the [TargetLocator](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html) `Interface` in `Selenium`.

A really simple example would look like this:

```
// Switch to new window
public String SwitchToNewWindow()
{
   // Get the original window handle
   String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

   foreach(String winHandle in driver.getWindowHandles())
   {
      driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
   }
   return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
}

// Switch back to original window
public String switchwindowback()
{
   String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
   driver.close(); 
   //Switch back to original browser (first window)
   driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
   //continue with original browser (first window)
   return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brandon.  I'm still a newbie with this stuff...would your suggested code go into selenium IDE, or would this be a separate file that would have to be called by Selenium IDE?

Comment: You are welcome for the reply.  This code would go into a class with your other tests.

Comment: OK thanks.  That's a little beyond the scope of what I've been doing, I think.  I actually tried inserting the code in IDE as a "runScript" command, with your code as the "Value".  Selenium IDE didn't complain, but the commands didn't work.  I guess I'll have to learn how to use this stuff in what we're doing.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am happy to help.  Feel free to shoot me an email (it's under my profile) if you want to discuss this further - outside of the site.  I may be able to help you structure your tests more effectively. I don't think technically you should mark this as an answer but, do you mind giving it an upvote for the effort?

Comment: Brandon, thanks so much for your generous offer of help.  I remembered that webdriver sometimes acts differently than running non-webdriver tests.  It turns out that using windowSelect followed by windowFocus gives me what I need when running webdriver tests.  I would happily give you an upvote, but when I try it tells me I need a "15 reputation" before I'm allowed to give an upvote :/

Comment: @user2761884 - I love to help so you are most welcome.  What you should do - since you answered your own question - is post THAT as the answer and then accept it so the question is asked and answered and then I can upvote that since you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered that webdriver sometimes acts differently than running non-webdriver tests. It turns out that using windowSelect followed by windowFocus switches between windows when running webdriver tests.

Comment: Glad you found your answer, +1.  Welcome to being able to up vote now :P